# Change author of the post after form sumbit - Post my CF7 Form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use plugin "Post my CF7 Form'

I have a form with “name” and contact “phone”, after sumbit plugin make a post with title of “name”

And I have this code to create a user with username of “phone” field:

```
function create_user_from_registration($cfdata) {
    if (!isset($cfdata->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission')) {
        // Contact Form 7 version 3.9 removed $cfdata->posted_data and now
        // we have to retrieve it from an API
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission) {
            $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }
    } elseif (isset($cfdata->posted_data)) {
        // For pre-3.9 versions of Contact Form 7
        $formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
    } else {
        // We can't retrieve the form data
        return $cfdata;
    }
    // Check this is the user registration form
    if ( $cfdata->title() == 'Форма заказа') {
        $password = $formdata['phone'];
        $email = $formdata['phone'].'@thechip.pro';
        $name = $formdata['phone'];
        // Construct a username from the user's name
        $username = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $name));
        $name_parts = explode(' ',$name);
        if ( !email_exists( $email ) ) {
            // Find an unused username
            $username_tocheck = $username;
            $i = 1;
            while ( username_exists( $username_tocheck ) ) {
                $username_tocheck = $username . $i++;
            }
            $username = $username_tocheck;
            // Create the user
            $userdata = array(
                'user_login' => $username,
                'user_pass' => $password,
                'user_email' => $email,
                'nickname' => reset($name_parts),
                'display_name' => $name,
                'first_name' => reset($name_parts),
                'last_name' => end($name_parts),
                'role' => 'author'
            );
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
                // Email login details to user
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
                $message = "Welcome! Your login details are as follows:" . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $username) . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $password) . "\r\n";
                $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
                wp_mail($email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);
            }
        }
    }
    return $cfdata;
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'create_user_from_registration', 1);
```

Help me please, how I can make my new user to the author of created post?

I trying to use this code

```
add_action('cf7_2_post_form_submitted_to_profile', 'new_profile_mapped',10,4);
/**
* Function to take further action once form has been submitted and saved as a post.  Note this action is only fired for submission which has been submitted as opposed to saved as drafts.
* @param string $post_id new post ID to which submission was saved.
* @param array $cf7_form_data complete set of data submitted in the form as an array of field-name=>value pairs.
* @param string $cf7form_key unique key to identify your form.
* @param array $submitted_files array of files submitted in the form, if any file fields are present.
*/
function new_profile_mapped($post_id, $cf7_form_data, $cf7form_key, $submitted_files){
  //do something.
 
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login' => $cf7_form_data['phone']
    );
    
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($userdata);
        if($user){
            $arg = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_author' => $user->ID,
        );
        wp_update_post( $arg );
    }

}
```

But it not working, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an issue here with this `get_userdatabylogin($userdata);`

Try replacing with this

```
function new_profile_mapped($post_id, $cf7_form_data, $cf7form_key, $submitted_files){
  //do something.

    $user = get_user_by('email', $cf7_form_data['phone'].'@thechip.pro');
        if($user){
            $arg = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_author' => $user->ID,
        );
        wp_update_post( $arg );
    }

}
```